# Автоматическое тестирование Calabash-Cucumber

Tags: android, android-testing, cucumber

I need help! 
Может кто сталкивался - подскажет. Не могу запустить процесс тестирования командой `calabash-android run name_app.apk`. Выдает вот такую ошибку:

> Unable to activate calabash-android-0.9.0, because json-2.0.2
>   conflicts with json (~> 1.8) (Gem::ConflictError)

Пробовал применить [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936206/how-to-launch-calabash-android-on-os-x-ruby-gems-dependency-error) решение - не помогло.
Вот результат команды `gem list json`:

> json (default: 2.0.2, 1.8.6)
>
> multi_json (1.12.1)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman все команды выполнились, gemfile заполненый скопировался в нужную директорию. При запуске выдает все ту же ошибку

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вот результат ' json (default: 2.0.2, 1.8.6)
multi_json (1.12.1) '

Comment: @MikhailVaysman запустилось! Тест запустился, прошел шаги и упал (так задумано - целью было проверить работоспособность). Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте **Gemfile** как описано по вашей ссылке и запускайте тест вот так

```
bundle exec calabash-android run name_app.apk
```